# Script to download sequentially named files, rename them, and delete smaller files

Tags: bash, http, web-scraping, network-file-transfer

I've written a little script to download sequentially named files, rename them, and delete files smaller than an certain number of kilobytes. I came up with this but I'm not too happy.  Any advice for me?

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
echo -n "Start file #:"
read start
echo
echo -n "End file #:"
read end
echo

wget --progress=bar:force http://www.mybox.com/pictures/show_pic.asp?src_id={$start..$end} 2>&1 | progressfilt

sleep 1

for file in *.asp
do
    mv "$file" "${file%.asp}.jpg"
done

find * -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg" -size -300k -delete

echo "tasks completed...exiting"
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

- [`sh` is not `bash`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments#Scripts). This shouldn't be a problem for your script though, because I don't think there are any [bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) in there.
- [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). If there had been another parameter in the URL you would have needed an ampersand (`&`) in there, and that's the special character to run a command in the background. That's one of many ways to trip up if you don't comment basically any non-trivial string.
- You don't need to `sleep`, because the `wget` commands are synchronous.
- That said, you might get a result much faster if you run them in parallel, by doing several `wget […] &` commands followed by a `wait`.
- You don't need to `exit` at the end of a shell script. That's only useful if you want to exit prematurely or with a different exit code from the previous command.
- If you use Bash you can use `read -p "Start file #: " start` etc. to avoid most of the `echo`ing.
- However, it is much more common to make shell scripts take parameters instead of being interactive, making the script even simpler:

  ```
  start="$1"
  end="$2"
  ```
- Use `set -o errexit -o nounset` (and `-o pipefail` if you're really in Bash) to make sure you catch any common bugs early.
- I'm not sure what `progressfilt` does, but you can suppress the `wget` progress bar by using `--quiet`.
- To be done slightly faster you should swap around the deleting and the renaming.
- Rather than `find *` you should use `find .` to avoid exceeding the maximum argument length. This is a good practice in general, but will only really break with *lots* of files.
- One very common feature of *nix scripts is that they are silent unless there's something *important* to report. Therefore, I'd remove the last `echo`.

Your script should now be 9 SLOC, and clean as a whistle!